# Can OS X play AMR files?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, audio

I have an AMR-format audio file which I recorded with my HTC Desire. I would like to send it to somebody who has a Macbook Pro. Will he be able to play it without jumping through hoops?

Answer (score 4):

QuickTime Player claims to open AMR files.  I don't have any AMR files to test it, though.

Comment: I can confirm that QuickTime X can play AMR files. I just downloaded one and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) will play them.